# Python loop printing output twice

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, printing, while-loop

I posted this problem before but it was closed given an answer that didn't help :/ 
So i'm posting it again to see if i can get a different answer. I'm doing a practice problem where I take an input of the speed a vehicle and the number of hours at that speed. The output should be a table listing the distance at every hour. The code i wrote does what i want it to do but it prints the output twice and i'm not sure why. 
Here's my code:

```
def main():
  another_speed = 'y'

  while another_speed == 'y' or another_speed == 'Y':
      calc_distance()
      another_speed = input('Do you have another speed?')

def calc_distance():
    speed = float(input('What speed were you going?'))
    hour = int(input('How many hours were you traveling at that speed for?'))

    print("Hour\tDistance Traveled (mi)")
    print('---------------------------')

    for hour in range(1, hour +1):
        distance = speed * hour
        print(hour,'\t',distance)

main()

****************
OUTPUT:

What speed were you going? 40(ENTER)
How many hours were you traveling at that speed for? 4 (ENTER)
Hour    Distance Traveled (mi)    ------
---------------------------             |
1       40.0
2       80.0.                           |   <--- All i want to print          
3      120.0
4      160.0.                      -----
Hour    Distance Traveled (mi)
---------------------------
1       40.0                     
2       80.0                          <--- Not this again!
3      120.0
4      160.0
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. I only see the desired output printed once.

Comment: Hmm. i'm using  Jupiter  notebook and refreshed my kernel and its still showing an output like that.. not sure whats wrong.

Comment: I tried running your code in a notebook in both JupyterLab and the classic Jupyter Notebook. Still not reproducing your error? What version of Jupyter Notebook are you using?

Comment: You might also want to copy-and-paste the code that you posted *here* into a notebook, just to make sure that your problem doesn't come from running an older version of your code.

Comment: I attached how i answered the problem below maybe you could answer my second question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out it was my text editor. I'm using Jupiter notebook. I was refreshing my kernel when my program got stuck '[*]' but did not ever try refreshing my kernel and **clearing my outputs.**

I created a new note book ran my code and it ran beautifully so i new it wasn't my code. So i went back to my old notebook and refreshed my kernel and cleared my output and now it works there too.

Although i solved my original answer. I would appreciate if someone went a little more into depth about the difference between refreshing the kernel and refreshing the kernel and clearing outputs if theres certain situations for when to use each one or if its just more advantages to refresh my kernel and clear my output every-time my program gets stuck and doesn't execute.  Thank you!

Comment: I think it might be best for you to make a separate question on SO about the difference between refreshing the kernel, refreshing the kernel and clearing outputs, etc.